# Prevent Tab navigation through Lightning datatable

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

I am working on lightning datatable and I want to prevent TAB navigation through cells. Any ideas on that? I can't just simply put index tab to -1 because I am using custom editable datatable and I need to read cells values by custom events.

I tried to add notab="notab" and prevent default on tab keyup but I am not sure where to put js since connectedCallback as a start wont work.